# Let $z \in \Bbb Z_m$, when is $z^2 \equiv 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

Let $z \in \Bbb Z_m$. When is $z^2=1, (z\neq1)$?

I know that for $m$ prime, $z=p-1$ is it's own inverse, but what about nonprime $m$?

Is $p-1$ the only self inverse element in $\Bbb Z_p$ ?

Comment: You need to characterize the solutions over $\Bbb Z_{p^n}$ and then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: To be fair, $1$ is also a "self inverse element".

Comment: Yeah, my bad, forgot to rule that out.

Comment: For a power of an odd prime, there are $2$ solutions. For $2^a$ there are $4$ solutions if $a\ge 3$. $2$ solutions if $a=2$. and $1$ solution if $a=1$. Now stitch together using CRT. For example if $m=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_t^{a_t}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct odd primes, there are $2^t$ solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd prime throughout.

**Claim 1**: In $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, the only numbers $n$ such that $n^2 \equiv 1$ are $\pm 1$.

*Proof*. Suppose $n$ is such that $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Then we must have that $p \mid n^2 - 1 = (n+1)(n-1)$. Since $p$ is prime, we know that we then have $p \mid n+1$ or $p \mid n-1$. In the first case, we have that $n \equiv -1 \pmod p$, and in the second case we have that $n \equiv 1 \pmod p$. So we've proven the claim. $\clubsuit$

**Claim 2**: In $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, the only numbers $n$ such that $n^2 \equiv 1$ are $\pm 1$.

*Proof*. This is not actually conceptually any different, but I present this separately. Suppose $n$ is such that $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {p^n}$. The in particular $p^n \mid n^2 - 1 = (n+1)(n-1)$ as above. And in particular, $p \mid (n+1)(n-1)$, so that either $p \mid n+1$ or $p \mid n-1$. Since $p > 2$, we cannot have that $p$ divides both, so $p$ divides exactly one of $n+1$ or $n-1$. Thus $p^n$ divides exactly one of $n+1$ or $n-1$. In the former case, we have that $n \equiv -1 \pmod {p^n}$. In the latter, $n \equiv 1 \pmod {p^n}$. So we've proven the claim. $\clubsuit$

**Claim 3**: In $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, there are $1$ and $2$ solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1$, respectively.

*Proof*. You can simply do it, checking manually. $\spadesuit$

**Claim 4**: In $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 3$, there are exactly $4$ solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1$. They are given by $x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod {2^{n-1}}$.

*Proof*. This is similar to the above proofs, but slightly more annoying. Again suppose that $x$ satisfies $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {2^n}$. Then $2^n \mid (x+1)(x-1)$. But since the difference between $x+1$ and $x-1$ is $2$, we will have that one will be divisible by $2$ and the other divisible by $2^{n-1}$ (note that they cannot both be divisible by $4$ for instance). If $2^{n-1} \mid x+1$, then we have that $x \equiv -1 \pmod{2^{n-1}}$. If $2^{n-1} \mid x-1$, then we have that $x \equiv 1 \pmod{2^{n-1}}$. When raised to $2^n$, these give the $4$ solutions mod $2^n$. $\clubsuit$

We now appeal to the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to patch together different congruences mod different primes. In particular, we get $2$ choices of congruence class per odd prime and either $1, 2,$ or $4$ choices for powers of $2$. So if $n = 2^{a_0} p_1^{a_1} \ldots p_k^{a_k}$, then we have $2^k \cdot T(a_0)$ choices of congruences classes from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, where $T(0) = T(1) = 1, T(2) = 2$, and $T(a) = 4$ for $a \geq 3$.
And so this is the number of square roots of $1$ mod $n$. $\diamondsuit$

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  $p-1$ is its own inverse in $Z_p$ because $(p-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ because $p \mid (p-1)^2 -1$ which is $p \mid p^2 -2p$ which is $p \mid p(p-2)$ which is obvious

Now $1$ is also it's own inverse in $Z_p$ because $1 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and so $p \mid 1-1 =0$ and any integers divides zero and so $p \mid 0$

Now in general $z^2 =1$ in $Z_m$ happens when $z^2 \equiv 1 \pmod m$ that is $m \mid z^2 -1$ that is this happens when there exists an integer $k$ such that $mk = z^2 -1 \implies 1 = z^2 - mk$

Now you should realise that this can't happen if the $gcd(z,m) \neq 1$

And of course $1$ will always have that property for any $m$ that is $1^2 =1$ in any $Z_m$.

However, take $Z_4$, No elements have inverses except for $1,3$ because $gcd(1,4) =1$ and $gcd(3,4) =1$ and we already showed that $1$ is it's own inverse, and notice that $3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ because $4 \mid 9 -1 = 8$ and so $3$ is also it's own inverse.

But the question remains, is every element that is invertible a self inverse ?

Not true. Consider $Z_{10}$, $3$ is invertible because $gcd(3,10) =1$, However, $3^2 \not \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$ because $10 \not \mid 3^2 -1 =8$

In fact the inverse of $3$ is $7$ because $3 \times 7 \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$, we have: $\,(\pm1)^3=(\pm3)^2=1$.